# Undefined local storage item on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

Any ideas on how to view localStorage on IE 10? I'm in the IE developer tools and then I'm trying to add the localStorage into Watch,  but it says that it's undefined. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to devtool (F12) --> go to "Console" tab and enter localStorage.

OR

Try to add it on the watchlist: "Script" tab -> observe -> enter localStorage & refresh for see the change.

Even i am using the same.Just refresh and check :

[image]

Comment: I'm in the script tab and I just can't find the observe... Thanks btw

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I debugged my code and actually window.localStorage.length is undefined. So that's why I'm getting the undefined object on the watch list